# unable to show image characters in java class

Tags: java, string, utf-8, utf-16, utf

I supposed to show/atleast print attached characters in a string
    String str = (attached)[image: str]

```
 System.out.println("Str : "+Str);
```

But I am unable to print the exact chars. I did use UTF 8 and 16 encode.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't simply ask new question when old one got down-voted. Try to improve original one: [unable to show image characters in java class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46200918)

Comment: How are you thinking that UTF-8 is involved? What is the string or byte sequence that you are starting with?

Comment: @Tom, it was sent from HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have what is known as a double encoding.

You have the three character sequence "你好吗" which you correctly point out is encoded in UTF-8 as E4BDA0 E5A5BD E59097.

But now, start encoding each byte of THAT encoding in UTF-8. Start with E4. What is that codepoint in UTF-8? Try it! It's C3 A4!

You get the idea.... :-)

Here is a Java app which illustrates this:

```
public class DoubleEncoding {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] encoding1 = "你好吗".getBytes("UTF-8");
        String string1 = new String(encoding1, "ISO8859-1");
        for (byte b : encoding1) {
            System.out.printf("%2x ", b);
        }
        System.out.println();
        byte[] encoding2 = string1.getBytes("UTF-8");
        for (byte b : encoding2) {
            System.out.printf("%2x ", b);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get it. But I want the out the glyph of the image should print on console.